# Code for calculating the perimeter of any polygon using classes (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

So i have here my main program (which i absolutely can't make any changes because this is how our instructor wants it to be run):

```
from class_point import Point
from class_polygon import Polygon

pt1 = Point(0,0)
pt2 = Point(0,4)
pt3 = Point(3,0)
polygon1 = Polygon([pt1,pt2,pt3]) #yes, the class Polygon will be initialized using a list
print(polygon1.get_perimeter())
```

So basically, i have two separate files containing the definitions of class Polygon and class Point.

This is my code for class Point which has  the function for calculating the distance between two given points:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def distance(self, second):
        x_d = self.x - second.x
        y_d = self.y - second.y
        return (x_d**2 + y_d**2) **0.5
```

And this is my code for class Polygon which will use the defined points and the distance function to calculate the perimeter of my polygon:

```
class Polygon():
    def __init__(self, points):
        self.points = points

    def __len__(self):
        len_points = len(self.points)
        return len_points

    def get_perimeter(self,points,len_points):
        perimeter = 0
        for i in range(0, len_points):
            pt1 = self.points[i]
            pt2 = self.points[i+1]
            perimeter += pt1.distance(pt2)
            if i + 1 == len_points:
                perimeter += points[-1].distance(points[0])
            else:
                continue
        return perimeter
```

But whenever i try to run the code, i get the error:

```
  File "C:/Users/Dust/Desktop/polygon_trial.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(polygon1.get_perimeter())

TypeError: get_perimeter() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'points' and 'len_points'
```

Comment: Why have you defined your `get_perimeter` method to take `points` & `len_points` as parameters? That is not required - you're not even using those in the method. That's what the error is about.

Comment: Oh, it doesnt? I thought it works similarly with accessing functions. So i tried to remove it, and now it shows the error "len_points and points as undefined"

Comment: You're not storing `len_points` anywhere even though you're calculating it in `__len__`. And you should access `points` with `self.points`

Comment: @rdas Hmm i dont understand. Wasnt the len() stored in the len_points variable?

Comment: No. Unless you do something like `self.len_points = len_points` nothing gets stored in the object.

Comment: @rdas should i use self.len_points = len(self.points) ?

Comment: Oh yeah, just what i was thinking lol. Thank you!

Comment: @rdas but now it gives me the error: 'Polygon' object has no attribute 'len_points' on the part for i in range(0, self.len_points)

Comment: Added an answer with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
class Polygon():
    def __init__(self, points):
        self.points = points

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.points)

    def get_perimeter(self):
        perimeter = 0
        for i in range(0, len(self.points)):
            pt1 = self.points[i]
            pt2 = self.points[i+1]
            perimeter += pt1.distance(pt2)
            if i + 1 == len(self.points):
                perimeter += self.points[-1].distance(self.points[0])
            else:
                continue
        return perimeter
```

Comment: You need to fix whatever algorithm you're using for calculating the perimeter. Obviously `i+1` won't work if `i` is `len(self.points)`

Comment: hmmm. Could you explain further?

Comment: @Gatts what's the algorithm you're trying to implement for calculating the perimeter?

Comment: i fixed it! pt1 should have been [i-1] and pt2 should be [i] but i adjusted my range and started with 1. Thank you so much for the help!